# SVG relative position

Tags: javascript, css, xml, svg

I have the following svg shape. How can I make it relative to the div container?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8421w8hc/20/

```
<div>

    <svg  viewBox="0 0 1000 2112" style="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

        <path id="ma" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="3" d="M276.53125,21.0625C270.2435,21.1337,264.6632,29.710064,257.625,38.15625C254.2095,42.255008000000004,246.70916,40.314622,242.1875,46.34375C236.65521,53.720438,230.99785,62.346888,226.46875,69.59375C215.85686,86.573459,230.16928,97.782258,212.125,111.1875C207.10965,114.77674999999999,201.08841999999999,115.97395,197.6875,119.375C192.96555,124.09715,192.80861,146.86201,183.5,153.84375C179.2572,157.02598,177.89186,161.88925,174.34375,165.4375C171.68483,168.09653,165.60417999999999,166.5658,163.375,170.28125C159.25578,177.1469,152.38471,200.19938,145.5625,203.6875C135.98604,208.58383,130.12789,210.84282,127.15625,215.15625C124.21798,219.42123,128.21307,221.02478,120.40625,232.65625C116.20943,238.90915,125.44735,245.58204,127.5,249.6875C130.03318,254.75407,121.95861,264.95404,121.4375,266.34375C116.03641999999999,273.13373,110.82711,279.75904,106.0625,286.90625C104.9172,288.62427,104.41387,291.14857,103,292.5625C101.23068,294.33189,100.92556,298.02625,99.375,300.09375C98.25112,301.59231,98.340978,305.27722,97.5625,307.09375C96.151137,310.38706,99.710576,316.2122,100.59375,319.15625C101.74974,323.00968,102.93777,328.35011,106.25,331C108.44205,332.75371,110.92774,335.24016,113,337.3125C115.21027,339.52286,119.50015,339.84377,122.125,341.34375C123.7939,342.29745,125.21469,344.74589,126.65625,346.1875C131.13587,350.66731,130.14474,359.6758,134.6875,364.21875C140.22073,369.7522,147.72669,372.17836,151.0625,379.40625C151.6216,380.61769,152.22093,382.11301,152.78125,383.75C153.30442,384.12705,153.81841,384.52134,154.34375,384.96875C159.49011,382.16219,192.47898,377.45858,194.125,375.8125C201.6757,368.26149,216.63142,331.12495,220.25,319.0625C223.11402,309.51541,224.60791,292.67363,231.75,285.53125C238.94927,278.33169,243.64201,268.57702,250.59375,261.625C255.44103,256.77752,268.37051,251.81277,270.40625,247.0625C272.02917,243.27554,261.87965,212.73681,268.09375,194.09375C273.12962,178.98553,292.55847,176.39929,295.6875,165.96875C298.4306,156.82473,307.59017,148.35643,312.5,138.78125C311.95901,138.28635,311.42663,137.7704,310.90625,137.25C306.57248,132.91606,301.96542,134.44373,297.34375,128.28125C294.72734,124.79256,299.28371,117.00322,296.53125,113.5625C293.76217,110.10102,290.4536,104.92346,289.03125,100.65625C286.52797,93.146115,292.375,82.479489,292.375,74.34375C292.375,72.274832,306.32062,71.292295,302.375,66.03125C298.36618,60.685944,297.79382,50.044012,293.28125,45.53125C290.88005,43.129956,297.01201,34.334683,294.71875,32.5C293.39881,31.444011,290.24045,33.879986,289.09375,31.96875C284.34165,24.048267,280.3039,21.019778000000002,276.53125,21.0625Z" stroke="#ffffff" fill="#e9eaee" style="cursor: default; stroke-linejoin: round;"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't position a `path` to anything on the page...only the SVG itself or the SVGs containing element.

Comment: Yes but how to do that because I have multiple shapes and each of them should be displayed in the same position.

Comment: Perhaps you could make an example for us to see. At the moment it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8421w8hc/20/

Comment: The SVG isn't in the #citymap div...is that intentional?

Comment: Yes, when you hover on a city the shape of the city should be displayed on the city_map div.

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution is, I suspect, a little more complex than we could go into here given your current technique. I would recommend, perhaps using `<defs` and `<use>` (or `<symbol>` rather than using Jquery to recreate each path in the other div. However, I'm still getting to grips with SVG myself so I will have to give it some thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want the map shapes on the left to all appear at the same place.

One way you can do that is to get the bounding box of the path and offset it by the x and y position.

```
$("path").hover(function() {
    var  bbox = this.getBBox();
    var d = $(this).attr("d");
    $("#city_map").html('<svg ... snip ...
      <path...  transform="translate('+(-bbox.x)+','+(-bbox.y)+')"></path></svg>');
});
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/8421w8hc/26/)